# retornar arquivos mais recentes em uma pasta

Tags: pandas, path

estou tentando retornar o path e a data de modificação de todos os arquivos em uma pasta, mas não estou conseguindo retornar a data, somente o path.

código até o momento:

```
from pathlib import Path
import pandas as pd

data_modificacao = lambda f: f.stat().st_mtime

directory = Path('path')
files = directory.rglob('*.*')
sorted_files = sorted(files, key = data_modificacao, reverse = True)

pathdf = list(sorted_files)
pathdf = pd.DataFrame(pathdf)
pathdf.rename(columns = {0:'path'}, inplace = True)

pd.set_option('max_colwidth', None)
pathdf.head(10)
```

a saída é um DataFrame ordenado pela data de modificação, mas somente com a coluna do path... como faço para retornar, também, uma coluna com a data de modificação?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from pathlib import Path
import pandas as pd
    
directory = Path('./')
files = list(directory.rglob('*.*'))

raw_data = [[item.name,item.stat().st_mtime] for item in files]

df = pd.DataFrame(raw_data, columns=['Nome', 'Data'])
df['Data'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Data'], unit='s')
df = df.sort_values(by='Data', ascending = False).reset_index(drop = True)
```

1. Importando os pacotes
2. Setando o diretório e recebendo a lista de arquivos
3. Criando uma lista de listas com o nome e a data de modificação
4. Criando o Data Frame
5. Convertendo a coluna Data no tipo datetime
6. Ordenando os dados de acordo com a coluna Data

Comment: muito bom, funcionou!

outra solução que encontrei, utilizando o meu código, seria criar um DataFrame com a data a partir do sorted_files e depois unir com o DataFrame já criado para o path, assim a coluna da data não ficaria com a formatação stat().st_mtime ao lado da datetime.